# Getting rank of row in OrderBy desc Eloquent query, How can i make this query work in laravel 5.5 eloquents?)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to give my users a ranking number for my Laravel hiscores pagination table.

This is the MySQL query I found working.
I am trying to put make this work as a Laravel eloquent query.

```
select @i := @i + 1 ranking, t.*
from (select @i:=0) initvars, users t  ORDER BY wins DESC;
```

My Laravel eloquent query right now:

```
$ranking = User::orderBy('wins', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Laravel 5.5 * sorry.

Comment: Please [edit your title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47824688/edit), don't just add a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is my solution.

I first added this function to my User Modal Class.

```
public function getRanking(){
   $collection = collect(User::orderBy('wins', 'DESC')->get());
   $data       = $collection->where('id', $this->id);
   $value      = $data->keys()->first() + 1;
   return $value;
}
```

Now in my view I run my getRanking() function.

```
@foreach($ranking as $key => $rankings)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $rankings->getRanking() }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('profileView', ['id' => $rankings->id]) }}">{{ $rankings->username }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $rankings->wins }}</td>
        <td>{{ $rankings->losses }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I am using my array keys to determine the user ranking.

Answer (score 6):

```
$table = (new User)->getTable();
$select = \DB::raw("@i := coalesce(@i + 1, 1) ranking, {$table}.*")
$users = User::select($select)->orderByDesc('wins')->paginate(5);
```

In the above, you need to select `table.*` again because even if you use `addSelect` instead of `select` eloquent loses the original column selection. I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended behaviour, but i'll investigate.

To clarify, if you just do

```
$raw = \DB::raw("@i := coalesce(@i + 1, 1) ranking");
$model->addSelect($raw); // this way
$model->select($raw); // or this way
```

The only field you will see on your model is `ranking`.

--

What might be of note is that if you're paginating based on something which fluctuates like ranking you may see some unexpected behaviour. For example if page 1 shows users a, b, c, d, e (rank 1-5 respectively) and user f climbs the ranking to position 5 before the visitor clicks to page 2, they'd see user e (now rank 6) again and not see user f (now rank 5) when on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL native `RANK()`:

```
$table = (new User)->getTable();
$select = \DB::raw("*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY wins DESC) as rank")
$users = User::select($select)->orderByDesc('wins')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using collections for large datasets, try this instead

```
$rankingSelect = DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET( wins, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wins
                ORDER BY wins DESC) FROM users )) AS ranking");

$ranking = User::select(['*', $rankingSelect])
            ->orderByDesc('wins')
            ->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score -1):

A very late answer but may be useful to some. New to laravel as well and using Laravel 8. I had the exact same problem and using laravels default $loop property I added in my blade template {{$loop->iteration}}.
ie

```
    @foreach($toptwentys as $toptwenty)        
       <tr>
         <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>        
         <td>{{$toptwenty->name}}</td>
         <td>$ {{number_format($toptwenty->annual_cost)}}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable