# how to add an auto increment field in laravel api resource

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to make a ranking for my users based on thier point and what i want to do is to order them by points and set a ranking field to it . i am using laravel api resource and in resource i want to add a field called `ranking` and ++ it so by the order user be ranked from 0 to n

```
   $data = User::with('city')
                    ->withCount('point')
                    ->orderByDesc('points_count')
                    ->get()
        ;
        $data = $data->where('points_count', '!=', 0);
        return UserPointResource::collection($data);
```

and here is my resource :

```
 return [
            "id"       => (int)$this->id,
            "fullname" => $this->fullname,
            "city"     => $city ? $city->name,
            "count"    => (int)$this->points_count,
        ];
```

so i want to add a field under count in resource named ranking to ++ each time it shows a user and shows user ranking . thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824688/getting-rank-of-row-in-orderby-desc-eloquent-query-how-can-i-make-this-query-wo

Comment: this is one is doing it in blade but i am trying to get it in resource which i cant do a foreach on it

Comment: this might help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in **User** model like this:

```
    /**
 * Get the User's Rank.
 * @param int $id
 * @return int
 */
public function getRank($id){

    $collection = User::with('city')
        ->withCount('point')
        ->orderByDesc('points_count')
        ->get();

    $data       = $collection->where('id', $id);

    //using array keys to find user rank
    $value      = $data->keys()->first() + 1;


    return $value;
}
```

Then in your `UserResource` you call the function like so:

```
 return [
        "id"       => (int)$this->id,
        "fullname" => $this->fullname,
        "city"     => $city ? $city->name,
        "count"    => (int)$this->points_count,
        "rank"     => $this->getRank((int)$this->id),
    ];
```